# What is the derivative of $||BB^T - Q||_2$ wrt matrix B?

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to optimize a function including the following expression $||BB^T - Q||_2$ where both $B$ and $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ (other conditions on $B$ are enforced by regularization).  One way to approach this is to form a generalized energy function and perform gradient descent, however I'm not familiar with using derivatives wrt. a matrix (here $B$) and the Matrix Cookbook doesn't seem to offer clear guidance on this case.

Is this even a sensible approach?  If so, is there any advice for how to approach this and specifically the $||BB^T - Q||_2$ term?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\spec#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_S}
\def\two#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_2}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$The Frobenius product $(:)$ is very convenient
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} = B:\LR{A^TC} \\
}$$
If $\two{\cdot}$ denotes the Frobenius norm, then the gradient can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \frob{BB^T-Q} \\
\phi^2 &= \frob{BB^T-Q}^2 \\
 &= \LR{BB^T-Q}:\LR{BB^T-Q} \\
2\phi\:d\phi &= 2\LR{BB^T-Q}:\LR{dB\,B^T+B\:dB^T} \\
  &= 4\LR{BB^T-Q}B:dB \\
d\phi &= 2\phi^{-1}\LR{BB^T-Q}B:dB \\
\grad{\phi}{B}
 &= 2\phi^{-1}\LR{BB^T-Q}B \\
\\
}$$
**However,**  if $\two{\cdot}$ denotes the Spectral norm,
then one must use the SVD decomposition
$$\eqalign{
X &= \sum_{k=1}^n \s_k u_k v_k^T &\qiq \spec{X} = \max_k \LR{\s_k} \\
\phi &= \spec{X} = \s_1 &\qiq d\phi = {u_1 v_1^T}:dX \\
}$$
Then substitute for $X$
$$\eqalign{
X &= {BB^T-Q} \\
d\phi &= \LR{u_1 v_1^T}:\LR{dB\,B^T + B\:dB^T} \\
 &= \LR{u_1 v_1^T + v_1 u_1^T}B:dB \\
\grad{\phi}{B}
 &= \LR{u_1 v_1^T + v_1 u_1^T}B \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you @greg! Your answer is very clear and helpful to me beyond this specific question - apparently I can't upvote your answer yet as I'm new, but I will!

Comment: to clarify - does the progression from the line: $2(BB^T-Q) : (dBB^T + BdB^T)$ to $=4 (BB^T-Q)B : dB$ (and the corresponding lines in the spectral norm answer) rely on $B$ being symmetric?  In my case, $B$ won't, in general, be symmetric.  Thank you

Comment: Note that $BB^T$ is symmetric for **any** $B\:$ (it's even true for a rectangular matrix).